# How can I go to multiple Activity screens from one page in Android Studio

Tags: android-intent, android-studio, onclicklistener, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I have 4 ImageButton's on my mainActivity screen. I would like to be able to click each button which will lead me to different screens.

When I try to run my application, it gives me an error stating that the "method onClick(View) is already defined in class MainScreen" I don't know how to rename the onClick method. I would appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to have one onClick method. Merge all the other cases in one switch-case block:

```
public void onClick (View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.imageButtonMarketing:
            ImageButtonMClick();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonBusinessAdmin:
            ImageButtonBClick();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonFinance:
            ImageButtonFClick();
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonHospitality:
            ImageButtonHClick();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I do that? Can you help me out?

Comment: onClick (View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.imageButtonMarketing:
                ImageButtonMClick();
                break;
            case R.id.imageButtonBusinessAdmin:
                ImageButtonBClick();
                break;
        ...
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks again for your help